# How to skip the ngFor when the respond from api is not completely in angular?

Tags: html, angular, angular9

Currently I already able to display out all the results in the front end.
But how can I make the ngFor only display those objects without **$ref** and must include the **Name** and **Description** in the array?

> **component.html**

```
<body>
    <app-header></app-header>
    <div class="container body-content">
        <br>
        <h2>Title</h2>
        <br>
        
        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Value</th>
            </tr>

            <tr *ngFor="let group of groups ">
              <td>{{group.Name}}</td>
              <td>{{group.Description}}</td>
              <td>{{group.value}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

</body>
```

> Respond from API

[image]

Comment: Please add your response as json/text, I can't see uploaded images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add a if condition

```
<ng-container *ngIf="groups && groups.length">   <!-- if length is greater than 0 -->
     <tr *ngFor="let group of groups ">
<ng-container *ngIf="(!group.$ref) && group.Name && group.Description"> <!-- to check your case which keys should be there to print <td> -->
                   <td>{{group.Name}}</td>
                  <td>{{group.Description}}</td>
                  <td>{{group.value}}</td>
</<ng-container>
                </tr>

<ng-container>
```

**[Edit]**

As most of answer recommends pipe way. (I too will suggest to use that , just the thing is i use generic pipe or if the same logic needs to be there in multiple places.

**just to extends references taken from other answer posted**  i will recommend to use below pipe, as it a generic you just pass **allow ** props like ['Name','Description'] and **disallow** props ['$ref']. it will loop through every property , kind of can be used in multiple places.  (it can further be optimized taking care in other factors.)

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";

@Pipe({
  name: "filterOutObject",
  pure: false,
})
export class FilterOurObjectWithRef implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items: any[] , allow = [], disallow = []): any {
    if (!items) {
      return items;
    }
    // check every allowed and disallowed props
    return items.filter((obj) => { 
       return allow.every((prop) => obj[prop] !== undefined) && disallow.every((prop) => obj[prop] === undefined)
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: This is too much of a hustle in my opinion, better to use pipe that will filter out unnecessary objects

Comment: sure , if similar type of requirement is there in project , then better to have a generic pipe , that can work in all the places.

Comment: @LogicBlower You way by using ng-container works. But I'm still interested on by using the pipe. Still try on the pipe filtering way

Comment: @LogicBlower Well you can parameterize your pipe and give it a key name of the property you want to filter out. Just add one parameter alongside `items` in pipe and pass it html as `let group of groups | filterOutObjectWithRef:"$ref"` Of course you would change name of the pipe to more generic type and reuse it anywhere you want. And also you will get `<tr>` element even if you have `$ref` as property

Answer (score 1):

You will have to write a pipe to achieve that.

In your template file:

```
<tr *ngFor="let group of groups | myfilter">
```

In your pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'myfilter',
    pure: false
})
export class MyFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(items: any[]): any {
        if (!items) {
            return items;
        }
        // filter items array, items which match and return true will be
        // kept, false will be filtered out
        return items.filter(item => (!Boolean(item['$ref']) && Boolean(item.Name) && Boolean(item.Description));
    }
}
```

In your appModule:

```
import { MyFilterPipe } from './pipes/my-filter.pipe';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        ..
    ],
    declarations: [
        MyFilterPipe,
    ],
    providers: [
        ..
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using Angular pipe filtering for that.

Your HTML:

```
<body>
    <app-header></app-header>
    <div class="container body-content">
        <br>
        <h2>Title</h2>
        <br>
        
        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Value</th>
            </tr>

            <tr *ngFor="let group of groups | filterOutObjectsWithRef: 'dsc' ">
              <td>{{group.Name}}</td>
              <td>{{group.Description}}</td>
              <td>{{group.value}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

**filter-out-objects-with-ref.pipe.ts**

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";

@Pipe({
  name: "filterOutObjectsWithRef",
  pure: false,
})
export class FilterOutObjectWithRef implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items: any[], sort: "asc" | "dsc" = "asc"): any {
    if (!items) {
      return items;
    }

    return items
      .filter(
        (item) =>
          item.$ref === undefined &&
          item.Name !== undefined &&
          item.Description !== undefined
      )
      .sort((a, b) => {
        if (sort === "asc") {
          return a.Name > b.Name ? 1 : -1;
        } else {
          return a.Name < b.Name ? 1 : -1;
        }
      });
  }
}
```

Declare this Pipe class in your module or component, and you will filter out all objects with `$ref` property

Comment: I confuse in ts part.
Where should I create the pipe in my existing ts?

My current ts is like this
`
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-program',
  templateUrl: './program.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./program.component.scss']
})
`

Comment: Sorry, not sure how to make it show properly in comment

Comment: Just reacte new file `filter-out-objects-with-ref.pipe.ts` export that class, declare it in your module where you component that you mention will use and you will be able to use it.

Comment: Great, glad I helped :)

Comment: By the way after get the result how can I sort the data inside the <td>?

Comment: If you are thinking about `<tr>` order you can sort that in the same pipe for filtering just do `.sort()` after filter, or make another pipe that does sorting and chain it with filter pipe `let group of groups | filterOutObjectWithRef | myNewSortPipe`

Comment: Which part you mean to implement for that .sort() ? if i want to use the same pipe to sort for the name

Comment: I will add part for sorting in my answer

Comment: I added sorting part in the same pipe. You just send asc or dsc to sort by ascending or descending order

Answer (score 0):

You first check if the response was valid:

```
<body>
    <app-header></app-header>
    <div class="container body-content">
        <br>
        <h2>Title</h2>
        <br>
        
        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Value</th>
            </tr>
<div *ngIf="CHECK IF RESPONSE WAS CORRECT">
            <tr *ngFor="let group of groups ">
              <td>{{group.Name}}</td>
              <td>{{group.Description}}</td>
              <td>{{group.value}}</td>
            </tr>
</div>
        </table>
    </div>

</body>
```